# StagingError: in user code: when calculating gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow

So i am trying to create custom training loop for my model, but when i connected it to tpu_strategy, it gave me stagingError. i tried to find code in official documentation of tensorflow but it didnt helped me. can anyone tell me solution for this problem?

```py
def train_step(step, x_batch_train, y_batch_train):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        
        pred = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
        if step % 100 == 0:
            importantArray.append(pred)
                
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, pred)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    
    return loss_value

@tf.function
def distributed_train_step(step, x_batch_train, y_batch_train):
  per_replica_losses = tpu_strategy.run(train_step, args=(step, x_batch_train, y_batch_train))
  return tpu_strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                         axis=None)


epochs = 32
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
    
    total_loss = 0
    num_batches = 0
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dist_ds):
        total_loss += distributed_train_step(step, x_batch_train, y_batch_train)
        num_batches += 1


    print(total_loss/num_batches)
```

And this is error given by the tensorflow:

```
StagingError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_13/513656419.py", line 18, in distributed_train_step  *
        per_replica_losses = tpu_strategy.run(train_step, args=(step, x_batch_train, y_batch_train))
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_13/513656419.py", line 12, in train_step  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py", line 269, in apply_gradients  **
        self.apply(grads, trainable_variables)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py", line 330, in apply
        self._backend_apply_gradients(grads, trainable_variables)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/base_optimizer.py", line 380, in _backend_apply_gradients
        self._backend_update_step(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/optimizer.py", line 107, in _backend_update_step
        tf.__internal__.distribute.interim.maybe_merge_call(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/optimizer.py", line 121, in _distributed_tf_update_step  **
        distribution.extended.update(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/optimizer.py", line 118, in apply_grad_to_update_var  **
        return self.update_step(grad, var, learning_rate)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/adam.py", line 123, in update_step
        m = self._momentums[self._get_variable_index(variable)]

    IndexError: list index out of range
```